# Bash: How to iterate a number without repetition in the same line?

Tags: bash

I am trying to iterate from 1 to 100, but the text is repeated 100 times, and what I want is to iterate only the number. I have looked in the bash documentation, I have looked for similar questions but I cannot find what I am looking for, can someone help me? Thanks!

Here my code:

```
for number in $(seq 1 100); do
    echo "Number: $number"
```

The output is:

```
Number: 1
Number: 2
Number: 3
Number: 4
Number: 5
Number: ...
```

And I am trying that the script runs in the same line:

```
Number: 1, later 2, later 3...
```

Iterating but in the same line.

I searched a lot but I didn´t find nothing similar...

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use escape character carriage-return (`\r`) to send the cursor back to the start, and use `-n` to avoid the new-line in echo.

```
for number in $(seq 1 100); do
  echo -en "\rNumber: $number";
  sleep 0.1;
done
```